# Error parsing spec file: expected value at line 186 column 5 (rococo-local)

Tags: error, chainspec

I'm trying to build raw from a plain chainspec. But all the time there is a complaint about line 186, where the quotes are located.

Docker Image version: v1.4.0'
Maybe it depends on the version of bash?

Comment: Please paste the L186 here.